# Splitting traceback stack into structure in go

Tags: go, logging, stack, traceback

I'm looking for a way to write to log a traceback stack in golang, but only some lines from it. As I see it, it could be done by splitting the result obtained from debug.Stack() into a slice of structures, which could be then easily parsed.

this is what I get now with this call "fmt.Println(string(debug.Stack()))":

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0xc0000c0050, 0x2, 0x0)
        /go/go1.15rc1/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x9f
main.go_logger(0x4cc235, 0x11, 0x4ccf9d, 0x15, 0xc000090101)
        /go/src/ethernet_monitor/info.go:30 +0x290
main.temp(...)
        /go/src/ethernet_monitor/info.go:40
main.main()
        /go/src/ethernet_monitor/info.go:45 +0x52
```

and that is the way I want it to be split, similar to python's traceback.extract_stack() structure:

```
fileName: /go/src/ethernet_monitor/info.go
function: main.main()
lineNumber: 45
```

So the question is - is it implemented somehow already? I'm not very confident writing my own parsing function as I might miss some specific cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably better off using `runtime.Callers` to get the individual items rather than trying to parse the stack as bytes.

This is what `github.com/pkg/errors` does here: https://github.com/pkg/errors/blob/master/stack.go#L163:1. You can see that `runtime.Callers` is already capable of skipping some levels.

From the `uintptr` needed you can see, this is quite low level. You should however be fine just copying `callers` function and all it depends on over and use the `StackTrace` function to get a more usable stack of individual `Frame`s: https://github.com/pkg/errors/blob/master/stack.go#L155

The frames can then be enhanced to return the function name, file, line number etc. How to extract that information can be seen in the different private functions of the `Frame`: https://github.com/pkg/errors/blob/master/stack.go#L23

I've done the same in our local errors package to be able to adjust how the stack is printed. This can be adjusted in the `Format` function of a `Frame`.

Note: maybe not the simplest solution as this exposes you to some low level stuff, but I'd prefer it anytime over parsing the already printed stack.

Comment: Why not recommend `runtime.Callers` + `runtime.CallersFrames` + traversing them? I mean, you seem to recommend stuff from a 3rd-party package when all the required parts are there in the stdlib.

Comment: thank you both for suggestions. Haven't worked with frames yet, so will search in that direction. Sorry for not upvoting your comments as I have not enough score yet :)

Comment: I'm recommending to LOOK at `pkg/errors` how Dave Cheney did it, not recommending to USE `pkg/errors`. Everything that is needed exists in the standard library.

Comment: gtristan, you should be able to mark my answer as the accepted answer, if it helped you.